# Exclude audience category "All users" from Data Studio report

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-data-studio

I have created audiences that divide all the users to categories that are exclusive, user can belong only to one category at a time, and user always belongs to at least one audience. I want to represent the percentages of the users groups in an area chart. Sort of similar to demographic information like age group, but based on a custom user property.

In the codebase I set user id based on login account, and I set custom user property `product_amount`. Then in Google Analytics 4 I have created audiences 1) not logged in, 2) logged in, no products, 3) 1-4 products, 4) 4 or more products.

In Data Studio I create an area chart with following settings:

- Dimension: Date
- Breakdown Dimension: Audience name
- Metric: Audience name (Aggregation: Count Distinct)
- Breakdown dimension sort: Total users Descending
- Style Area chart: Show stack true, 100% Stacking true

Collecting data into audiences is not retroactive, so I'd assume having the All users audience in the past before audiences were created, makes sense. However, from the point of time all of the audiences are collecting data, I still have audience All users as non-zero, even though the custom audiences logically cover all possible users. What am I missing here?

Edit: I found out that I can add a control Drop-down list, which has the list of the audience names with checkboxes. If I uncheck any of the audiences, I get "Data Set Configuration Error" and in the details there is only "Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set".